# Filter only Numeric values from a line of Strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below two lines

"key1,c1,p1,10,t1,z1"
"key2,c2,20,p2,t2"

And I want the output as below

"key1,c1,p1,t1,z1"
"key2,c2,p2,t2"

I tried the below, however all the digits are being filtered.
Below is the output. Any suggestions ???

key,c,p,,t,z
key,c,,p,t

val data =spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List("key1,c1,p1,10,t1,z1","key2,c2,20,p2,t2"))

```
val filtered_data = data.map{line => line.filterNot(_.isDigit)}

filtered_data.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: If you've got a data set that's serialized as CSV, please, please, please don't leave it that way—use a CSV reader to read it into at least a `Seq[String]` or whatever, and then filter that using something like `.exists(!_.isDigit)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
val strings = List("key1,c1,p1,10,t1,z1", "key2,c2,20,p2,t2")
strings.map(_.replaceAll("([,|^]\\d+)", ""))
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ng5mH35iQEuFo2TYSk5SeQ